# Vhdl VGA Problem

Tags: fpga, vhdl, vga

I'm doing a fpga project in vhdl for my studies.

I'm displaying a dog on the screen that I try to move. That works well for right, left and up but trying to make the dog go down, it moves in a strange way: it's like the dog "scrolls", it's hard to describe but its not the dog that moves its kind of a window that moves on a list of following dogs.

If i move the  `else Spot <= '0'`  part of the code , other directions (right and down) became invalid (same error) .

here is  link of the video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npoi_ITIuNg

Here is the full code: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/67429007/Desktop.rar

Here is the bugging (I think) code part:

```
begin

if clk25'event and clk25='1' then
    if Compteur_pixels >= origineX and compteur_pixels < origineX + tailleX 
    and compteur_lignes >= origineY and compteur_lignes < origineY + tailleY  then
        Spot <= dog (ligne,Pixel); --dog and is an array of 0 and 1 
        Pixel := Pixel+1;


        if pixel >= tailleX then 
            pixel := 0; 
            ligne := ligne + 1;

                if ligne >= tailleY then 
                ligne := 0;

                     else Spot <= '0';

                if direction = "00011100" then     -- right key pressed (A)
                   if originex < 700  then
                         originex := origineX + 1; --increment X origin of dog
                    end if;

                elsif direction = "00011010" then -- left (w)
                    if originex > 83  then
                        originex := origineX - 1;
                    end if;

                elsif direction = "00111010" then -- up
                    if originey > 46 then
                        originey := originey - 1;       
                    end if;

                elsif direction = "01000010" then  -- down
                    if originey < 450  then
                        originey := originey + 1;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end if ;

end process ;
```

Comment: It looks as if you aren't erasing the old image of the dog when you move it to a new location.

Comment: it's not that because I display all the screen every time.

Comment: The algorithme is :
<pre>
For all pixel of the screen
  if we are in the position of displaying the picture 
   display the corresponding pixel
  else
   display a black pixel

if direction is up 
  origin of picture -- ;
 
etc.
.
.

Comment: but ... I think your `else Spot <= '0';` is in the wrong place.

Comment: I saw that to and I changed it but in a wrong way, I'm trying to correct it now :)  
  
I tell you

Comment: not working...

I moved the else under the secund if and closed the if.

I'll try later thx for your help.

I'm going to eat

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a friend, I wait for the Vertical Synchronisation signal to be equal 0 to make my picture move. It solved the problem because the sprite origin now changes only when the screen is near to be redraw.

Answer (score 0):

You have some white pixels ('1') on the edge or your dog array. If you just slide it like the algo does, then you will see the 'scrolling' bug you talk about. Make your array (i.e. sprite), have zeros on the edges if you want to move it one pixel at a time. Or you can just clear the screen and repaint on every cursor move.

Comment: Can you upload a video to show what happens? Maybe a waveform too?

Comment: Actually, Brian answered your question. Clear the area first them move the 'sprite'.

Comment: In fact it's not doing like a paint brush, there is distinct dogs one over an other.. I take a video

Comment: You gave a Smart way of solve the problem anyway I like it. But It's not mine :/  <br>
I would have prefer it was

Comment: Hre is the video  http://youtu.be/npoi_ITIuNg

Comment: Oh I was meaning my problem in the previous message :), It does not solve my problem. I'm sorry for the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

My earlier comments were wrong, because the scrolling is *within* the sprite area, with the rest of the screen clear. I couldn't tell that from your description.

Now I can see that when you move the origin of a partially displayed dog on screen, you do not adjust the Pixel and Ligne positions within the dog. So, moving the sprite in one direction, you move it OUT of the scan range and start re-drawing it at `(0,0)` in dog cordinates when you reach the next line.

Moving in the other direction you ought to skip a line. What was `(1,0)` or `(0,1)` in dog coordinates should now be `(2,0)` or `(0,2)` but you don't make that adjustment. However if you did, you would have to miss the first line or column of pixels and draw an incomplete sprite.

A better answer is to only detect sprite movement and process the origin when your pixel counter is outside the frame entirely. Or at least, outside the sprite in the Y axis.

Also, make the boundary values (83, 46 etc) not magic numbers but dependent on the sprite size, e.g. `VGA_height - Dog_height - margin;`

Comment: I see it seems to be the answer , i don't understand all the thing but I'll work on it :) Thanks Brian.

Comment: Yes that is what I was trying to do in fact, I only move the OriginX and the originY When the line counter of the sprite is equal to is maximum.

Comment: Actually, Even with the correction it does not work.  
In the code i change origin of dog only when the line counter is to '0'

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/67429007/Nouveau%20document%20texte.txt

here iss the revision